# Typescript- show loading animation while waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In Typescript I normally have

```
someFunction.then((data) => {
   //do stuff with resolved data from promise

}, (err) => {
   //do stuff with error
});
```

Sometimes the `data` takes a while to resolve in which case I would like to display a spinner (generic loading animation) while the promise is resolving. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I've looked at other questions and they seem to all require the use of ajax calls. I'm using AngularJS so I was wondering if there's a way to do it in the promise resolution.

Comment: It's basic logic. `showSpinner(); someFunction.then((data) => { hideSpinner(); }, (err) => { hideSpinner(); });`

Comment: It's too broad to answer but my best guess for a well elaborated system is to create some component directive that reacts to an event and show your spinner so that from your components you can emmit the event to show or hide your spinner. Also, I recommend you to implement a debounce for short operations not to require the spinner component to react on that.

Comment: 1-create a SpinnerComponent. 2-Create SpinnerService with two function show() and hide(). 3-provide the service in AppModule. 4-Import the service where you want to use it. 5- spinnerService.show() before your promise call. 6-spinnerService.hide() after your promise resolve and voila

Comment: sounds good thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes the data takes a while to resolve in which case I would like to display a spinner (generic loading animation) while the promise is resolvin

Use a variable to track it

```
loading = false
someFunction.then((data) => {
   //do stuff with resolved data from promise
   loading = false;
}, (err) => {
   //do stuff with error
   loading = false;
});
```

How you use this `loading` variable to show a spinner depend on your choice of framework. Since you are using AngularJS recommend a property on your Controller bound to an `ng-if` in your template.

Comment: Shouldn't `loading` be initialized to `true` right before the promise is invoked?